# django api framework getting total pages available

Tags: django

Is it possible to get how many pages an API request has available? For example, this is my response:

```
{
    "count": 44,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/ingested_files/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 44,
....
```

I'm pulling 20 elements per page, so there should be 2 pages in total, but currently the way it's set up I can get next and previous, but there's no context as to what the total amount of pages is. Sure I could do some math and get how many possible pages using the count, but I imagine something like this would be native to the framework, no?

This is my view:

```
 class IngestedFileView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = IngestedFile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngestedFileSerializer
```

This is my serializer:

```
class IngestedFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IngestedFile
        fields = ('id', 'filename', 'ingested_date', 'progress', 'processed', 'processed_date', 'error')
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can create your own pagination serializer:

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response


class YourPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
               'next': self.get_next_link(),
               'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'results': data
        })
```

In your configuration in `settings.py` you add `YourPagination` class as the Default Pagination Class.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.apps.pagination.YourPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}
```

References:

- [Custom Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles)

Comment: The total number of pages is available as an attribute of paginator? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.num_pages

Comment: Yeah it is an attribute in Django but not DRF, which is being used.

Comment: DRF is using django paginator? See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L177. So you should be able to access it by doing `self.page.paginator.num_pages` ?

Comment: how it can works without custom pagination I can't find .num_pages anywhere with default pagination

Answer (score 5):

You can extend **PageNumberPagination** class and override **get_paginated_response** method to get total pages count.

```
class PageNumberPaginationWithCount(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        response = super(PageNumberPaginationWithCount, self).get_paginated_response(data)
        response.data['total_pages'] = self.page.paginator.num_pages
        return response
```

And then in settings.py, add **PageNumberPaginationWithCount** class as the Default Pagination Class.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.apps.pagination.PageNumberPaginationWithCount',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 30
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, inside your view you can make a custom class pagination , and use it inside your CBV , and no need to add any extra codes inside your settings.py module , and here is a simple example :

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


from .serilizers import App1PostSerializer
from .models import Post

class MyCustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'page_size': self.page_size,
            'total_objects': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'current_page_number': self.page.number,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'results': data,
        })


class PostsView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = App1PostSerializer
    pagination_class = MyCustomPagination
```

output results:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "page_size": 2,
    "total_objects": 3,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "current_page_number": 1,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "post_user": 1,
            "post_title": "tt",
            "post_description": "ttt",
            "post_created_date": "2022-02-05T11:12:24.207985Z",
            "post_updated_date": "2022-02-05T11:12:24.207985Z",
            "created_by": "admin"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "post_user": 1,
            "post_title": "tt",
            "post_description": "tt",
            "post_created_date": "2022-02-05T11:12:30.155031Z",
            "post_updated_date": "2022-02-05T11:12:30.155031Z",
            "created_by": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is just example , and change it based on your requirement / case .
i hope this helpful.